# What is happening while adding object with navigation properies to Db?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've got class like that:

```
class City
{
    long CityId {get;set;} 
    string Name {get;set;} 
    List<House> Houses {get;set;} 

}
```

with filled `List<House>` with some Houses objects and I want to add `City` to db with `db.Cities.Add(someCity)`.

Is `Houses` also will be added automatically in that moment?

What I need to do to add also `Houses` automatically, assuming that my Navigation Properties are set up properly?

Comment: Why not simply try it out?

Comment: @HimBromBeere : Yes, forgive me for maybe silly question. I am sitting in front of large amount of code written without this concept and I wonder if I can simple make it simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they will, but take into account that if you do it this way, new `House` entries will be created in the table. If you want to associate existing houses you will need to add an entity retrieved from database.

Comment: Won't that depend on whether the `House` objects already have a valid ID / primary key?

Comment: If they have a primary key but they are not attached to the context, Entity Framework will attempt to insert them and an exception will be thrown. In that case you would need to call `Context.Houses.Attach(house)` for each house in the list. Entity Framework keeps track of every instance state, so it needs to know if it is modified or a brand new instance Entity Framework knows nothing about.